# Mongoose explicitly include a "hidden" field

Tags: mongoose

for security reasons I've added `select: false` to the `User`'s password field, so that it will not be queried by default. However, I'd like to know how to expliclity include it when querying the user on login requests.

My code looks like this right now:

```
User.findOne({email: 'abc'})
  .then(user => {
    ...
  }).catch(next);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Latest from npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `select: false` at query level as mentioned in the select property docs in the mongoose,

```
  /**
     * Sets default select() behaviour for this path.
     * Set to true if this path should always be included in the results, false
     * if it should be excluded by default. This setting can be overridden at
     * the query level.
     */
    select?: boolean | any;
```

So this can be done with `select('+password')` field, I have tested it and it's working.